# virsh: Connected to domain <name> Escape character is ^]

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt, virsh

I'm having an issue with viewing output from a virtual machine installed via `virt-install`.

[I first used this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309792/68573), but it left me with the following immediately after running:

```
Starting install...
Connected to domain ApacheServer
Escape character is ^]
```

It sits here forever and no input is accepted into the terminal at this point. After some googling around the web, I ended up destroying/deleting my guest, and starting over with the install, but this time, I had added 
`--console pty,target_type=serial` to the arguments being passed to `virt-install`. For some clarity, below is the complete install command I used last:

```
virt-install \
-n ApacheServer \
--description "CENTOS7 for Apache Server" \
--os-type=Linux \
--os-variant=rhel6 \
--ram=2048 \
--vcpus=1 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS7-Apache.img,bus=virtio,size=10 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--cdrom /home/server/Downloads/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso \
--network bridge:virbr0
```

This doesn't change anything for me. I am still stuck at `Escape character is ^]` after the install. I even closed this console window out, and tried to get into the guest via `$ virsh console ApacheServer`. This leaves me with:

```
Connected to domain ApacheServer
Escape character is ^]
error: operation failed: Active console session exists for this domain
```

**My current expectation is that after the install, or after issuing the `virsh console <domain name>` command, I should see the console/terminal output that the guest is putting out.**

Comment: I see the down vote here, but without any sort of critique, I'm not sure what to make of that, or how to change my question to be better. I posted my issue, the expected output, the actual output, and what I've done to get this far. I'm open to hearing about how I can make my question better.

Comment: Some people are just hard to please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, it turns out that specifying your boot device with `--cdrom /path/to/bootmedia.iso` can be problematic when it comes to viewing output during boot up. Trying to install again, I noticed this warning pop up before the `Starting install...` text:

> WARNING  CDROM media does not print to the text console by default, so
>   you likely will not see text install output. You might want to use
>   --location. See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media

I searched for this warning and found suggestions for adding the following to the `virt-install` args:
`--location /path/to/bootmedia.iso` en lieu of `--cdrom` 
and `--extra-args console=ttyS0`.

After making these two changes, everything worked. The complete working install command is as follows:

```
virt-install \
-n ApacheServer \
--description "CENTOS7 for Apache Server" \
--os-type=Linux \
--os-variant=rhel6 \
--ram=2048 \
--vcpus=1 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS7-Apache.img,bus=virtio,size=10 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--location /home/server/Downloads/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso \
--network bridge:virbr0 \
--extra-args console=ttyS0
```